# Passing string array from c to java jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, arrays

OK, i am doing a java native interface(jni) project, and i am trying to pass a string array from c++ to java. How is this done.  I cannot figure out how to do it. All i have tried to do is directly pass the array on and spend hours on Google. I have not tried anything else, because i do not know what to try.  I have seen posts and answers on how to do the conversion in the other direction, but not this way.  I have also seen it done with char arrays but that method looked complicated.

I have even tried this with an int array and it wont work

```
jintArray t[3];
return t;
```

Comment: Seems to me you'd use JNI to create a Java `String[]` object of the appropriate size, then use JNI to create individual `String` objects and insert them into the array.

Comment: but how do i take an array containing c strings and convert it to a java array containing java strings

Comment: When you say "c string" do you mean instances of `std::string` or pointers to `char`?

Comment: You write code.  After reading the appropriate specs.

Comment: ive tried and its not simple or straight-forward and im not sure if its even possible

Comment: Have you found the specs for JNI and whatever C string representation you're using?  With those you should have all the info you need.

Comment: ive tried not much information available

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you read about the `NewStringUTF` function in the [JNI specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations). It's really straight forward.